# Why the $\alpha-$divergence is defined in the following way (Information Geometry)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory, information-geometry

Let me define everything first 
Let $S$ be a manifold and suppose that we are given a smooth function $D=D(.||.):S\times S\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying for any $p,q\in S$
$$D()p||q)\geq 0\hspace{0.5cm} \text{and}D(p||q)=0 \iff p=q$$

Now for a convex function $f(u)$ on $u>0$ for each probability distribution $p,q$ lets define
$$D_{f}(p||q)=\int p(x)f(\frac{q(x)}{p(x)})dx$$ we call it the f-divergence.

Let us now define $\alpha-$divergence as $D^{(\alpha)}=D_{f^{(\alpha)}}$ for a real number $\alpha$ we define
\begin{equation}
  f^{(\alpha)}(u) =
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{4}{1-\alpha^2}\{1-u^{(1+\alpha)/2}\} & (\alpha\neq \pm1)\\
      u\hspace{0.5mm}logu & (\alpha=1)\\
      -logu & (\alpha=-1)
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

My question is why we have defined the $f^{(\alpha)}$ is the way it is defined I mean why we have the factor $\frac{4}{1-\alpha^2}$ what if I remove it and then define the function what problem will I face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $u > 0$ we have

$$\lim_{\alpha \to -1} \frac{4}{1-\alpha^2} (1 + u^{(1+\alpha)/2}) = -\log u,$$

so the factor makes $f^{(\alpha)}(u)$ continuous in $\alpha$ for $\alpha < 1$. Hence, its arguably the most natural choice.